# How do I clear selection of a gridview row?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using C# ASP.NET VS2010.

I have a GridView including a select command button.

This select button points to an action in the code behind C# page activated upon selection.

After performing all required action I would like to clear the selection.

For example: in case the ID="gvInfo" I would like to use something like gvInfo.Deselect();

How do I do that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As explained in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a4937d1-531a-49d7-9392-bb76cb9bfcb7/how-to-clear-selectedrow-in-a-gridview?forum=aspwebformsdata —

> Gridview has a property called SelectedIndex.   If you want to
> unselect any rows then set this property to -1.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```cs
gvInfo.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 6):

In desktop apps with `DataGridView` there is no `SelectedIndex`:

```
gridView1.ClearSelection();
```

Comment: in which asp.net version? i cannot find it

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way and it works perfectly.

```
gridViewName.GetSelectionModel().ClearSelection();
```

I hope it can work for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

```
GridView1.SelectRow(-1);
```